# Imgur api authentication PHP

Tags: php, api, imgur

I am trying to implement the imgur api in PHP, but I cannot get it to authenticate. Im using file_get_contents to get the results from the api, and ive set the header to contain my Client-Id.

```
 $opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
'method'=>"POST",
'header'=>"Authorization: Client-ID CLIENT_ID"
  )
 );

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

 $file = file_get_contents('https://api.imgur.com/3/image/$get', false, $context);
 echo $file;
```

But it still says "Authentication required" and returns the status of 401. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you registered your application? Why don't you try with a cURL request?

```
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();

// Set some options (including authentication header)
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'IMGUR_API_URL',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Authorization: Client-ID CLIENT_ID')
));

// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);

// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```

Some hostings don't allow remote file access with `file_get_contents()`

Comment: Echoing $resp gives a blank page, but there is no error or anything this time.

Comment: This is the first time ive tried to use the api since friday, and I never got the authentication to work on friday, so I dont think it would be that.